# How to make sure spring beans gets initialized before web.xml filters gets initialized in spring mvc world?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="3.0"
>

......

    <filter>
        <filter-name>FilterThatNeedsBean</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.abc.FilterThanNeedsBean</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>FilterThatNeedsBean</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

.....

</web-app>
```

I have spring-beans.xml

```
    <bean id="BeanA" class="com.cde.BeanA">
    </bean>
```

Getting error in init method of 'FilterThatNeedsBean' filter as 'BeanA' is not yet initialized for usage

How to make sure spring beans gets initialized before web.xml filters gets initialized in spring mvc world ?